# data.table column creation with `:=` and double indexing

Tags: r, data.table

I am processing a `data.table` instance and looking to create an extra column using `:=` this worked fine until I did some double indexing.

For the following instance of a `data.table`:

```
example_data= structure(list(V1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,1L, 1L), 
                             .Label = c("AUDUSD", "EURUSD", "GBPUSD", "NZDUSD", "USDCAD","USDJPY"), class = "factor"), 
                             V2 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
                              .Label = c("2007", "2008", "2009", "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014"), 
                             class = "factor"), 
                             V3 = c("1.RData", "10.RData", "11.RData", "12.RData", "2.RData", "3.RData", "4.RData", "5.RData", "6.RData", "7.RData")), 
                        .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3"), 
                        class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

which gives this data:

`example_data
        V1   V2       V3
 1: AUDUSD 2007  1.RData
 2: AUDUSD 2007 10.RData
 3: AUDUSD 2007 11.RData
 4: AUDUSD 2007 12.RData
 5: AUDUSD 2007  2.RData
 6: AUDUSD 2007  3.RData
 7: AUDUSD 2007  4.RData
 8: AUDUSD 2007  5.RData
 9: AUDUSD 2007  6.RData
10: AUDUSD 2007  7.RData`

I am looking to split the "V3" column on a "." and get the preceding number as a character in a new column in the same table.

Doing this is straightforward in normal R:

`example_data$MONTH = apply(example_data,1, function(x) { strsplit(as.character(x[["V3"]]),"\\.")[[1]][1]})`

I thought that doing this in `data.table` would be even more straightforward:

`example_data[,MONTH:=strsplit(as.character(V3),"\\.")[[1]][1]]`

However the double indexing is not being interpreted as I intended, because it is changing all values to the outcome of the first row. Removing the indexing does perform the correct operation (just not extracting and placing the data in the right place):

`example_data[,strsplit(as.character(V3),"\\.")]`

I also attempted to *internalize* the indexing by applying a function but got to the same wrong result:

`myfunc <- function(x) { strsplit(as.character(x),"\\.")[[1]][1] }
example_data[,MONTH:=myfunc(V3)]`

I can always use the standard R solution but if anyone knows of a `data.table` based solution that would be appreciated. I am not interested in other standard R or `(d)plyr` based alternatives (they are great - just not what I am asking).

Comment: You need the same `apply` (or better `sapply`) to get the first element of each list. But we should provide a function to do this conveniently. Could you please file an issue [here](http://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues)?

Comment: I will, `data.table` is so much quicker than some other options it is worth the syntax learning curve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `sub` instead of `strsplit`:

```
example_data[ , MONTH := sub("\\..*", "", V3)]

        V1   V2       V3 MONTH
 1: AUDUSD 2007  1.RData     1
 2: AUDUSD 2007 10.RData    10
 3: AUDUSD 2007 11.RData    11
 4: AUDUSD 2007 12.RData    12
 5: AUDUSD 2007  2.RData     2
 6: AUDUSD 2007  3.RData     3
 7: AUDUSD 2007  4.RData     4
 8: AUDUSD 2007  5.RData     5
 9: AUDUSD 2007  6.RData     6
10: AUDUSD 2007  7.RData     7
```

---

However, it works with `strsplit` too:

```
example_data[ , MONTH := unlist(strsplit(V3, "\\..*"))]
```

Comment: Sven, that's great! But note that `strsplit()` returns a list. You might have to `unlist()`.

Comment: @Arun Agreed. I added `unlist`.

Comment: +1. The `cSplit` approach from "splitstackshape" doesn't save us any work... :-( `cSplit(example_data, "V3", "\\..*", drop = FALSE, type.convert = FALSE, fixed = FALSE)`

Answer (score 1):

Just pushed two functions [`transpose()`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1025) and [`tstrsplit()`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1026) in *data.table v1.9.5*.

With this we can do:

```
require(data.table)
setDT(example_data)[, col := tstrsplit(V3, ".", fixed=TRUE)[[1L]]]
#         V1   V2       V3 col
#  1: AUDUSD 2007  1.RData   1
#  2: AUDUSD 2007 10.RData  10
#  3: AUDUSD 2007 11.RData  11
#  4: AUDUSD 2007 12.RData  12
#  5: AUDUSD 2007  2.RData   2
#  6: AUDUSD 2007  3.RData   3
#  7: AUDUSD 2007  4.RData   4
#  8: AUDUSD 2007  5.RData   5
#  9: AUDUSD 2007  6.RData   6
# 10: AUDUSD 2007  7.RData   7
```

`tstrsplit` is a wrapper for `transpose(strsplit(...))`. `transpose()` can also be used on *lists*, *data frames* and *data tables*. Please check the documentation and examples for more.

Comment: Now that is service for you - thanks - it is much appreciated.